# Exclude taxonomy term from all loops, but having it on widget

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop, query, exclude

I have excluded a custom post type taxonomy term from all posts like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );
function exclude_category_posts( $the_query ) {
    $taxquery = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'tag_ID',
            'terms'     => array( 157 ),
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        )
    );
    $the_query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    return $the_query;  
}
```

But I need that taxonomy term to be included back in a specific widget loop and only for that specific widget. Is there any chance for that?

The reason I followed the above way, because I have created a product category, which I'd like to be shown only on a widget I created and nowhere else except search queries and the taxonomy term page. On all other loops I'd like it excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've excluded a taxonomy *term*, not the whole taxonomy. Is that what you intended?

But on to the answer...

Right before your query in the widget add:

```
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );
```

And then you probably want to put it back again after that query by repeating:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );
```

That is a bit of a "dirty" method and assumes that this is your site and your widget. You may need something more complex if circumstances are different from that.

Comment: Thank you! Works fantastic. Except the taxonomy term page is empty now.

Comment: Have just added `if ( !is_tax() )` in my function and all is okay. And yeah, taxonomy term was excluded, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is there another way to exclude a taxonomy term from specific loops instead of `pre_get_posts`? For example a woocommerce slug, instead of editing directly a general loop.

Comment: You can exclude from specific loops but in a lot of cases the answer still involves `pre_get_posts`.  It is hard to say without more detail.